# Two outputs with blockproc

Tags: matlab

I have this function that calculates the value of the binary pattern of a 3*3 block which result form thresholding the 8 neighbers pixels with the center pixel and returns two outputs: the decimal value of the binary code, the same decimal value if it's uniform or 59 if not.

```
function [out1,out2] = lbpblock(im)
%... implementation details
out1 = decimal ;
out2 = uniform;
end
```

The problem is when trying to use blockproc like this

```
result = blockproc(im,[3 3],@lbpblock);
```

the result array is only two dimensions (eg. 85*85) and has only the first output.

when I tried

```
[res1 res2] = blockproc(im,[3 3],@lbpblock);
```

I get "Error using ==> blockproc Too many output arguments".
I tried to change the function signature

```
function out = lbpblock(im)
%... implementation details
out = [decimal, uniform];
end
```

the result array again two dimensions only but now (85*170) the first output is stored in odd columns and the second in even ones.
Is there any trick to get blockproc to store the result in a 85*85*2 array??

Comment: return only one argument in `lbpblock`, say `out`. Make it a structure or a cell array such that: `out.first=out1` and `out.second=out2`.

Comment: Unfortunately :\
Error using ==> blockprocInMemory at 80
Invalid output class.  The user function, FUN, returned an invalid result.
The class of the result was cell.
The class of the result was struct.

Comment: I don't understand the error. Did you do this: after `out1 = decimal ;
out2 = uniform;`, write `out.first=out1; out.second=out2`. Return only `out`. In the main file, write: `result = blockproc(im,[3 3],@lbpblock);`

Comment: Actually I did exactly what you said, but it looks like the blocproc doesn't accept struct because it's written in the description "a function that returns a matrix, vector, or scalar".
I also tried $out = {decimal  udecimal}; also get the class of the result was cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve an NxNx2 array as output by concatenating in the third dimension.

Example:

```
im = magic(10);
r = blockproc(im, [3, 3], @func);

function r = func(im)
r1 = mean(im.data(:));
r2 = std(im.data(:));
r = cat(3, r1, r2);
end
```

The important line is `cat(3, output1, output2)`.